# openSuSE termcap settings

Tags: opensuse, termcap

For some reason under openSuSE Tumbleweed I am unable to use different termcap entries. To be specific, I'm trying to use the **`pcansi-25`** termcap entry.

Anyone know why it's behaving like this?

Answer (score 1):

That's *terminfo*, not *termcap*.  Several packagers have put most of the terminal database into a separate package.

For instance, the [terminfo-base](https://software.opensuse.org/package/terminfo-base) is 152kb, while [terminfo](https://software.opensuse.org/package/terminfo) is 472kb according to the description (which seems low - unless the package is *source*, compiled at install-time by tic, while terminfo-base is distributed in binary format).  For reference, here is the package description of the latter:

> This is the **`terminfo`** reference database, maintained in the ncurses package. This database is the official successor to the 4.4BSD termcap file and contains information about any known terminal. The ncurses library makes use of this database to use terminals correctly. If you just use the Linux console, **`xterm`**, and **`VT100`**, you probably will not need this database -- a *minimal* **`/usr/share/terminfo`** tree for these terminals is already included in the **`terminfo-base`** package.

Offhand, I recall only Slackware still using *termcap*, and the database it installs was generated from ncurses' terminal database.

Some systems do not use termcap as such, but allow you to install it.  Checking my OpenSuSE 13, I see that there is an `/etc/termcap` generated from terminfo which is part of `terminfo-base`, but the terminfo entry which you need (pcansi-25) is part of `terminfo`.  It would be possible to generate a subset of the terminal database in `/etc/termcap`, but would complicate the package dependencies.  The packagers chose the simplest approach for this file.  However, it is unlikely that you *need* termcap, since all of the programs that OpenSuSE provides use terminfo.

Comment: No. /etc/termcap contains a pcansi-25 reference.

Comment: Ok. You were right. My bad. I installed terminfo. Apparently only terminfo-base was installed. It's working now.

Comment: Ok. This issue is solved. Whoever is in charge of deleting posts can do so now.

Comment: The convention is that if the answer works for you, it might work for others (so it doesn't have to be deleted).  And marking it accepted is like voting for the question.